# Issues with displaying icon on a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I am stuck with a silly issue. Please help. I want to display an info icon which, on click, should open a pdf. The icon does not get displayed although it exists in the server. However, when I'm pasting the same code on the console, it gets displayed. Following is the code-

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function open_win(){
 window.open("../resources/Devices_overview_explained_v1_final.png","_blank",
    "toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, 
    scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, copyhistory=yes, width=805, height=700");
}
</script>

<div id="sysOverview" style="width: 855px; margin-top: 40px;">
 <div class="title" style="margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;" align="center">
  Analyzed Devices Overview [<%
  Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
  int year = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
  out.println((year - 2) + " - " + year + "]");
 %>
     <input type="image" src="../resources/images/Infoicon_Intel.png" 
        class="tooltip_info_img" alt="" onclick="open_win()">
   </div>
</div>
```

[Screenshot showing the code works when pasted on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ACDu.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the line breaks in window.open you won't get an error.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function open_win(){
 window.open("../resources/Devices_overview_explained_v1_final.png","_blank", "toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, copyhistory=yes, width=805, height=700");
}
</script>

<div id="sysOverview" style="width: 855px; margin-top: 40px;">
 <div class="title" style="margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;" align="center">
  Analyzed Devices Overview [<%
  Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
  int year = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
  out.println((year - 2) + " - " + year + "]");
 %>
     <input type="image" src="../resources/images/Infoicon_Intel.png" 
        class="tooltip_info_img" alt="" onclick="open_win()">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your reply. I added the line breaks while posting the code here. In the original code, there are no line breaks.

Comment: I'm not getting any error message. The icon just doesn't get displayed on the webpage.

Comment: Try setting a width and height on the image.